# Custom C++ Predicate and find if

Tags: c++, stl, set, predicate

So I have an assignment that has this data structure

```
    struct ZipCode
{
    char s[4];
    int  zip;
    bool operator() (const ZipCode &lhs, const ZipCode &rhs) const
    {return lhs.s[1] < rhs.s[1];}
    bool operator() (const char* st, const int &z) const
    {return st == s && z == zip;}
    bool operator() (const int &z) const
    {return zip == z;}

};
```

I am then inserting an array of these into an STL:set and am trying to find one that has a specific zip later. I do this by using find_if like this

```
std::set<ZipCode, ZipCode>::iterator itz = find_if(mySet.begin(), mySet.end(),ZipCode()(0xbb77));
```

When I compile it I get the following error:

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(83): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

I'm not sure what the problem is or how to fix this problem

Comment: You didn't ask about this part yet, but I will tell you `st == s` does not do what you think it does in this expression: `bool operator() (const char* st, const int &z) const {return st == s && z == zip;}`

Comment: Wow ya I'm a little surprised I missed that. swapped it to `strcmp(st,s)`

although it was working and I'm mildly surprised that it was now that you pointed it out.

Comment: You might luck out on string constants if the compiler folded them to share the same storage.  ie. `"abc"` on line 100 and `"abc"` on line 200 might be in the same place in the resulting executable, so pointers to them would compare as equal out of sheer luck.  No way would I depend on that behavior, though.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because operator() is a member function and so the one you use takes two parameters, `this` and 0xbb77.

You can use `set::find` instead.

If you want to search by using different class member values you must provide three constructors to `ZipCode`, where each one takes the same parameters as one of the operator() overloads. Then add an operator==(const ZipCode& other) function and get rid of the operator()s.

I'd type it out but it's hard to do on an iPad

Answer (score 0):

First of all, making a structure both the storage for your information *and* the functor with three different uses is bad design. It's too convoluted. I almost thought that `std::set<ZipCode, ZipCode>` was illegal.

Second, the clean solution to your problem should be a map. `std::map<int, std::array<char, 4>>`. The STL generic algorithms know nothing about the nice properties of whatever data structure is in `std::set` (usually a red-black tree), so use `map::find` instead.